# Proof that $n$ must be a multiple of $m$ given these sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, divisibility

Let $A=n \mathbb{Z}$, the set of all integer multiples of some integer $n$, and let $B=m \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $A \subseteq B$. Prove that $n$ must be a multiple of $m$.

So far, I have the following:

Let $x \in A$. Then, $x=kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Because $A \subseteq B, x=l m$ for some $l \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, $lm = kn$.

However, if you then solve the equation for $n$, you obtain $n=\frac{l}{k}m$, which is not necessarily an integer. What is the proper way to complete this proof? I have already proven the converse as part of the exercise but I am having trouble applying the logic in this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n=1*n$ so $n\in A\subset B =$ {the multiples of $m $}.

So $n$ is a multiple of $m$.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I think that this will work within my professor's specifications, but I guess I'll find out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since $n\mathbb Z\subseteq m\mathbb Z$ we have that $n\in m\mathbb Z$. Therefore, there is some $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $n=km$.

Comment: While this makes sense to me, I am taking an introductory proof writing course, and my professor instructed us to begin with letting $x \in A$. I don't understand how to proove that any arbitrary $x$ in $A$ is also in $B$.

Comment: You don't need to proof that any arbitrary $x$ of $A$ is also in $B$, because this is given!
To add a little more detail, you can write something like: "Since $n\mathbb Z\subseteq m\mathbb Z$ and $n\in n\mathbb Z$ we have that $n\in m\mathbb Z$..."
Is this question part of another problem? Or is this a problem on its own?

Comment: The only other part of this problem is proving the converse. I understand your proof and why it works, but unfortunately my instructor gave specific directions for how to prove this problem (i.e. that we should begin with some $x \in A$ and prove that it is also in $B$).

Comment: Why would your professor do that? We don't care about artery values of x.  We only care about n.